# replace underscores with dashes in url with htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

Want to change all `_` in url to `-` (hyphens).

E.g:

```
www.mauriclick.com/mauritius_holiday_rentals/apartment/Oasis_Villas_Mauritius
```

should become

```
www.mauriclick.com/mauritius-holiday-rentals/apartment/Oasis-Villas-Mauritius
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
str_replace('_','-',$url);
```

Comment: Although correct, it seems OP's asking for a solution using .htaccess

Comment: OP doesn't seem to know what he's asking for since he tagged both PHP and htaccess.